# Nested xml binding to CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-binding

I have a nested xml file which contains menu and submenus. I need to bind it to the ASP.NET CheckBox control on page load. Please see the code below.

I am trying to bind using the C# code below:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {

        //Reading the data from  the XML file
        ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/menu.xml"));
        DataView dataview = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
        BioCheckBoxList.DataSource = dataview ;
        BioCheckBoxList.DataBind();            
     }
```

XML:

```
enter code here
<!--<menu>
  <menuItem text="Home" url="~/Default.aspx?id=e058511b-b7d9-4d39-b194-cf803014777" mid="08f360dc-   a9cf-4724-a595-66f7ca01c04e" predeficon="homeico" />
  <menuItem text="Bio" url="~/Default.aspx"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="Reg" url="~\Modules\Bio\Reg.aspx"/>
      <menuItem text="Mem" url="~\Modules\Bio\Mem.aspx"/>      
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>    
  <menuItem text="Por" url="~/Default.aspx?"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="General">
        <subMenu>
          <menuItem text="Make Appointment" url="~\Modules\Portals\Gen.aspx"/>          
        </subMenu>
      </menuItem>
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>
</menu>-->
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't say what the problem is, maybe the cause is that the xml is commented out (`<!--` at beginning and `-->` at end)?